# Salvando Arquivo no Sublime Text 3 em ISO-8859-1

Tags: sublime-text-2, sublime-text

Quando eu tento salvar um arquivo mudando o ***encoding*** para ***Western(ISO 8859-1)***, aparece a seguinte mensagem de erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

alguém sabe o motivo ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso acontece quando o arquivo possui caracteres inválidos ou "anormais" como `β` do idioma alemão.

Se você habilitar a opção "draw_white_space: all", o sublime mostrará uma bolinha, onde tem espaços em brancos e um traço onde tem um *tab*, e se tiver um espaço em branco sem nada, é um carácter inválido, remova-o.

[image: Carácter inválido]

**Você também pode ir em `File > Reopen with Encoding -> Western (ISO 8859-1)` que todos os caracteres inválidos serão convertidos.**

Answer (score -1):

Realmente, o meu arquivo possuia caracteres inválidos como o @kaduAmaral mencionou acima,
mas infelizmente o sublime não me mostrava quais eram os caracteres.
Eu tive que abrir o arquivo com o **Notepad++**, fui em *formatar>Conjunto de caracteres>Europa Ocidental>ISO 8859-1*.
Com isso, o Notepad me mostrou os arquivos inválidos tais como: ***InÃ-cio, DescriÃ§Ã£o, ediÃ§Ãµes*** e outros.... eu apaguei e coloquei primeiramente os caracteres válidos  tipo: **Inicio, Descricao e edicoes**, salvei o arquivo e abri novamente com o ***Sublime***, e tentei novamente salvar o arquivo com o ***encoding ISO 8859-1*** e deu certo, depois eu coloquei novamente as palavras com a acentuação.

Se tiverem alguma outra reposta mais prática agradeço !

Comment: Atualizei ali a resposta. ;)